# Can't work around Max Execution Time exceeded error while importing Wordpress Theme Unit Testing Data

Tags: php, wordpress, unit-testing, wordpress-theming, fatal-error

I was trying to import the [Wordpress Theme Unit Testing Data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test) when this error occured and its driving me nuts.

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in E:\WebServer\w3programmers\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 1511
```

List of things I've tried:

1. Changed the `max_execution_time` to a hour! in the php.ini
2. Changed it to unlimited (0)
3. Changed it in my htaccess file
4. Tried Changing it with `set_time_limit()` in the config file
5. Tried Changing it with `ini_set()`
6. Tried using this plugin [WP Maximum Execution Time Exceeded](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-maximum-execution-time-exceeded/)

Nothing works. I even tried running the import from the Command Line using the WP-Cli tool.
Yes, even the cli failed with the same error. I checked by echoing the return value of `ini_get("max_execution_time")` at the start of my config file. and yes, it does output the value I set in the `php.ini` and other places.

I thought the PHP was hardcoded to allow limitless execution time in the cli. Is this a PHP Bug? or a Wordpress Bug?

I'm using XAMPP on Windows. PHP 5.5.11.

Comment: did you restart apache after changing the .ini settings? did you check if .htaccess is even enabled? but yes, generally CLI-mode php has the time limit disabled. Maybe something in php code elsewhere is re-enabling the limit AFTER you've tried all of your changes.

Comment: @MarcB Yes Sir. I have.

Comment: @MarcB Good call! I'll Investigate your lead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, searched and found this solution that fixed it for me: [WordPress 4.2 Fatal error – Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded](http://simpleglyph.in/wordpress-4-2-fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-60-seconds-exceeded/)

Basically, it instructs you to add `set_time_limit(1000)` or however many seconds you want to the line before the error in the script that times out so in your case add it on line 1510 in your class-http.php file.

I realize this is 6 months after you asked but maybe it'll help someone else with this problem!

Comment: Thank you very very much. I truly have no words to thank you. I've wasted my whole freaking day behind this worthless issue until I found your solution. Thats a ton. You deserve a medal for this answer. You saved the  day my dear.

Comment: You are so welcome! I completely understand your pain, it's exactly what happened to me!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to also set

```
php_value post_max_size xxxM
php_value upload_max_filesize xxxM
php_value memory_limit xxxM
php_value max_execution_time xxxxxx
php_value max_input_time xxxxxx
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime xxxx
```

so in .htaccess you'd have if you have .htaccess reading enabled

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value post_max_size 000M
php_value upload_max_filesize 000M
php_value memory_limit 000M
php_value max_execution_time 000000
php_value max_input_time 000000
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 0000
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this sloved for me by changing set_time_limit call inside wp_get_http() in wp-includes/deprecated.php, like this:

```
set_time_limit(1200); // Limit to 20 minutes
```

More on the source of the error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37156901/2504037).